# Reading error's in PHP and fixing them

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am new to php, I have a error with my code and am having problems identifying the error.

**error says:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/ob219/public_html/membership/classes/DB.php on line 12

it could just be me not seeing a simple mistake, but if its not and if there is a flaw in the logic of my code i would appriciate some help explaingning the problem.
Thank you.

**and code is:**

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . config::('mysql/db'), config::get('mysql/username'), config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo / forgot the method name:

```
config::('mysql/db')
```

Should probably be something like:

```
config::get('mysql/db')
```

Comment: As far as `reading errors` goes in PHP.  Syntax error means there was a general error with parsing the PHP (not specific to an undefined variable, method, etc).  It occurred at line 12 where there was an unexpected `(` (after `config::`).  PHP was expecting a String, variable, `{`, or `$`.  In this case you needed a String defining the method name.

Comment: This makes sense, since `get` is inside all the others and is missing from `mysql/db` --- Yet, is it in fact a typo causing the error, as Sam explained? @Beep

Comment: @Fred -ii- that's what I thought due to I have corrected it before and makes no diffrence

Comment: @Beep `config::` means that you are calling either a static method or a static property of the `config` class, so it needs to be followed by a method name or a variable name or a variable containing the variable name or method name in curly quotes. What is the code and the error you have now?

Comment: @jeroen I appreciate the explanation, its now throwing a error that I have a bug in my init file. http://stuweb.cms.gre.ac.uk/~ob219/membership/index.php

Comment: @Beep That's an easy one, it cannot find the file so you need to make sure it's at the right place and your auto-loader is set up correctly (by the looks of it you use one).

Comment: ahh fixed it I had config when the class is Config .... @jeroen thanks for your help.

Comment: `Another Happy Ending`